# How to create a list of elements in columns based on another in R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | 4 |
| x | 2 | 5 |
| x | 3 | 6 |
| y | 1 | 4 |
| y | 2 | 5 |
| y | 3 | 6 |

I want to combine the elements in the 2nd and 3rd columns as a list based off of what they corresponded to in the first column like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | [1, 2, 3] | [4, 5, 6] |
| y | [1, 2, 3] | [4, 5, 6] |

How do I go about doing this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution using dplyr returns lists for the values (not sure if you wanted character strings or lists but the brackets in your example led me to think you wanted lists...)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(col1) %>% 
  summarise(across(, list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% group_by(col1) %>% summarise(col2 = str_c('[',toString(col2),']'))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  col1  col2     
  <chr> <chr>    
1 x     [1, 2, 3]
2 y     [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `tidyr::pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = col1,
              values_from = -col1,
              values_fn = list)
```

The default `values_fn` is `list` so it's technically not needed here, but to suppress the warning message I made it explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Using `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(.~ col1, df1, list)
  col1    col2    col3
1    x 1, 2, 3 4, 5, 6
2    y 1, 2, 3 4, 5, 6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y"), col2 = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), col3 = c(4L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L, 6L)),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```